# Using Python's jellyfish module to get best match (partial string matching)

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to create a dictionary of some kind to append my results and get the best match using the jaro distance function.

This is part of my attempt to match 2 lists and get the best matched name in both.

Example:

```
import jellyfish
jellyfish.jaro_distance(u'jellyfish', u'sellyfish')

output: 
0.9259259259259259
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
listA = ['grellofish','mellofush','jellyfihs','sellyfish','salmonfish']
listB = ['jellyfish','salmonfish']

#convert to unicode
listA = [unicode(i) for i in listA]
listB = [unicode(i) for i in listB]

for nickB in listB:
    for nickA in listA:
        results = jellyfish.jaro_distance(nickA, nickB)
        print nickB,nickA,results

output:
jellyfish grellofish 0.825925925926
jellyfish mellofush 0.777777777778
jellyfish jellyfihs 0.962962962963
jellyfish sellyfish 0.925925925926
jellyfish salmonfish 0.685185185185
salmonfish grellofish 0.733333333333
salmonfish mellofush 0.7
salmonfish jellyfihs 0.618518518519
salmonfish sellyfish 0.755555555556
salmonfish salmonfish 1.0
```

In this case I want it to return the 2 with the highest score:

```
jellyfish jellyfihs 0.962962962963
salmonfish salmonfish 1.0
```

For FuzzyWuzzy users, I am trying to emulate the `process.extractOne` function where you can pass a list into `process.extractOne(<value you want to compare>,<list of items you want to compare>)` and you will get the best match.

Reason why I am not using FuzzyWuzzy is just cause processing is too slow and I am unsure what is happening behind, a match for 5000 strings comparing to another list of 5000 strings take up to 40 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solve your problem:

```
def get_closest_match(x, list_random):
    best_match = None
    highest_jaro_wink = 0
    for current_string in list_random:
        current_score = jf.jaro_winkler(x, current_string)
        if(current_score > highest_jaro_wink):
            highest_jaro_wink = current_score
            best_match = current_string
    return best_match
for nickB in listB:
    result = get_closest_match(nickB,listA)
    print nickB, result
```

Comment: This was the solution I used! Thanks for answering anyways.